# How to send back form results to the Script Editor Web Part which displays the modal dialog

Tags: 2013, modal-dialog

This relates to SharePoint 2013 Online.

On my home page I have a SEWP which determines if currentUser has registered some details we need. If not then open a ModalDialog window displaying a form to submit the details.

I've removed the ajax calls in code below, as they're not an issue, so the pertinent stuff is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sitePath = '/teams/company/site/subsite1/subsite2';

function isUserRegistered() {
    var login = _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName;

    // currentUser is not registered so display modal...

                var options = {
                    url: sitepath + '/Lists/Users/Register.aspx?IsDlg=1",
                    width: 800,
                    height: 600,
                    showClose: true,
                    title: "Welcome " + firstName + ",",
                    dialogReturnValueCallback: dialogResult
                };
                SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);

}

function dialogResult(result, response) {
    switch(result)
    {
        case SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel:
            console.log('result = cancel'); break;
        case SP.UI.DialogResult.invalid: 
            console.log('result = invalid'); break;
        case SP.UI.DialogResult.ok:
            alert('OK'); break;
    }
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("isUserRegistered");
</script>
```

The Register.aspx was created in SPD 2013 by navigating to the All Files > Lists > Users and then choosing File > ASPX file.
I added my html and script for handling Save button click:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="default" runat="server"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveDetails(CellNo, Company, CarReg, AccessCard) {
        var results = {
            CellNo: CellNo.value,
            Company: Company.value,
            CarReg: CarReg.value,
            AccessCard: AccessCard.value
            };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.ok, results);
    }
</script>   
</head> 
<body>  
<form id="userInfo" runat="server">
    <div style="background-color:lightgray;">
        <div>
            <br />
            <h3>Cell no.: <input name="CellNo" type="text" /></h3>
            <h3>Company: <input name="Company" type="text" value="Tesco" /></h3>
            <h3>Car registration: <input name="CarReg" type="text" /></h3>
            <h3>Tesco access card number: <input name="AccessCard" type="text" /></h3>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" onclick="return saveDetails(CellNo, Company, CarReg, AccessCard)">Save</button>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem I am having is that when I click 'Save' the page complains that SP is undefined.

So how can I reference SP.js in order to close modal and pass back results to parent page? (Or alternative method if it achieves the same objective.)

Thanks.